# Link a program object again

Tags: opengl-es, hyperlink, shader

I have a program object which can be rendered successfully.

But sometime in my application at runtime, when I modify and compile its vertex & fragment shaders source, re-link it again by `glLinkProgram()`, I see the program can not be rendered.

Note that: the shaders and program were re-compiled/re-linked successfully.

I just check their status by

```
glGetShaderiv(fsId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus); 
and glGetProgramiv(progId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus); 
the result is compileStatus = linkStatus = 1
```

I'm wondering we can re-linking a program object in OpenGL ES 2.0 or not?

My GPU info:

```
GL_RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 530
GL_VENDOR: Imagination Technologies
GL_VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you? By the OpenGL ES specification, yes. *Should* you? No.

The general rule when doing anything in OpenGL, even ES versions, is this: don't do *anything* unless you know it's commonly done. The farther off the beaten path you go, the more likely you are to encounter driver bugs.

In general, the usage pattern for programs is to link them, then use them a bunch, then delete them when you're closing the application. You should stick to that. If you need a new program, you create a *new program*.

Re-linking is going to trash all your uniform state anyway. So it's not like you're preserving something by re-linking inside an old program instead of creating a new one. Indeed, it's better this way; if the new link fails, you still have the old program. Whereas if you re-link on a program and it fails, the old data is *destroyed*.